# Apache https proxy without SSL certificate

Tags: apache, https, proxy, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

How can I set up proxy which listens on https and proxies the requests to other server on https without setting up SSL certificate on Apache for inbound https requests?

I just need to proxy the request over https connection.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the SSL certificate in question on your apache box, it will be very difficult to set up proxying.  The site configurations usually rely on the `Host` header and the URI path, which you won't have if you can't unwrap SSL.

Instead, if all SSL traffic is to be forwarded unconditionally, you might consider a TCP proxy instead of an application proxy.

There are several ways of setting this up, and it will vary depending on your chosen platform.  If you're running on Linux, you can easily set up an [`iptables` rule](https://serverfault.com/a/140626/176705) to forward requests to 443 to some remote host.

Comment: I need something like follows on apache 

`<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.otherdomain.com

SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass / https://www.otherdomain.com
ProxyPassReverse / https://www.otherdomain.com
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: See, there's the problem.  In order to process virtual hosts, Apache needs to decode the `Host` header, which it can't do without decrypting the stream.  Even if you don't use multiple hosts for that IP address, Apache's processing pipeline can't handle that.  You'll have to use a different kind of proxy.

Comment: Can I redirect from https to http without having server certificate?

Comment: No.  How would your http service know how to decrypt the stream?

Comment: If I haven't made the handshake in the first place, there would be no need to decrypt the stream.

Comment: If you can get it to work, write it up.  That would be a very interesting article.

Comment: The site name can be found from the [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) field of the https request, and it should be enough to forward the content even without the certs. If apache can't do it, it is an apache problem and not because it would be impossible.